# grails Jquery DataTable resouce inlucde not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to include jquery database java scripts using resouce module.

created the new project added this code in buildconfig:

```
compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
compile ":jquery-datatables:1.7.5"
```

crated these two files main.jsp and index.jsp.

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/1.%20Overview.html#1.1.3%20Edit%20your%20Sitemesh%20layout

added this take in the index.jsp

```
 <jqDT:resources/>
```

but its not including the datatable javascript and css.

not sure what I am missing. please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used this layout now its including the Jquery datatable files.

```
<html>
<head>
<title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails" /></title>

<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
<g:javascript library="application" />

<g:layoutHead />
<r:layoutResources />
<jqDT:resources />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <g:layoutBody />
    </div>
    <r:layoutResources />
</body>
</html>
```